# How to set Image on Canvas..? and then draw on Image

Tags: android, canvas

i want to set image on white canvas and want to draw on that image i don't know how to do that. i tried all possible method, but not work. this is my code help me if u want any other code then tell me. and please help me......

```js
package com.example.drowingdemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawingView extends View {

 // drawing path
 private Path drawPath;
 // drawing and canvas paint
 private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
 // initial color
 private int paintColor = 0xFF660000, paintAlpha = 255;
 // canvas
 private Canvas drawCanvas;
 // canvas bitmap
 private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
 // brush sizes
 private float brushSize, lastBrushSize;
 // erase flag
 private boolean erase = false;

 public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
  setupDrawing();
 }

 // setup drawing
 private void setupDrawing() {

  // prepare for drawing and setup paint stroke properties
  brushSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.medium_size);
  lastBrushSize = brushSize;
  drawPath = new Path();
  drawPaint = new Paint();
  drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
  drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
  drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
  drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
  drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
  drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
  canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
 }

 // draw the view - will be called after touch event
 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
  canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
 }

 // size assigned to view
 @Override
 protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
  super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
  canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
 }

 // register user touches as drawing action
 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  float touchX = event.getX();
  float touchY = event.getY();
  // respond to down, move and up events
  switch (event.getAction()) {
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
   drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
   break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
   drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
   break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
   drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
   drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
   drawPath.reset();
   break;
  default:
   return false;
  }
  // redraw
  invalidate();
  return true;

 }

 // update color
 public void setColor(String newColor) {
  invalidate();
  // check whether color value or pattern name
  if (newColor.startsWith("#")) {
   paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
   drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
   drawPaint.setShader(null);
  } else {
   // pattern
   int patternID = getResources().getIdentifier(newColor, "drawable",
     "com.example.drowingdemo");
   // decode
   Bitmap patternBMP = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
     patternID);
   // create shader
   BitmapShader patternBMPshader = new BitmapShader(patternBMP,
     Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
   // color and shader
   drawPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
   drawPaint.setShader(patternBMPshader);
  }
 }

 // set brush size
 public void setBrushSize(float newSize) {
  float pixelAmount = TypedValue.applyDimension(
    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, newSize, getResources()
      .getDisplayMetrics());
  brushSize = pixelAmount;
  drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
 }

 // get and set last brush size
 public void setLastBrushSize(float lastSize) {
  lastBrushSize = lastSize;
 }

 public float getLastBrushSize() {
  return lastBrushSize;
 }

 // set erase true or false
 public void setErase(boolean isErase) {
  erase = isErase;
  if (erase)
   drawPaint
     .setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
  else
   drawPaint.setXfermode(null);
 }

 // start new drawing
 public void startNew() {
  drawCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
  invalidate();
 }

 // return current alpha
 public int getPaintAlpha() {
  return Math.round((float) paintAlpha / 255 * 100);
 }

 // set alpha
 public void setPaintAlpha(int newAlpha) {
  paintAlpha = Math.round((float) newAlpha / 100 * 255);
  drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
  drawPaint.setAlpha(paintAlpha);
 }
}
```

Comment: what do you have problems with?

Comment: no problem but i want to set image in stand of an canvas i want to draw on image

Comment: so use drawCanvas for drawing, not default View's Canvas

Comment: i did it but when i draw line with brush its draw when i take my funger from screen at that ime my drawing is not show in image?

Comment: i dont know what you really mean...

Comment: i mean when i m draw line on image its show line but when i stop drawing an take my finger from screen then my drawing as gone for ex. i write latter M and when i take my finger from screen M is not seen .......did u get wht i mean?

Comment: probably you call startNew() somewhere

Comment: there is startNew but its call when press for make new canvas.

Comment: just setup some breakpoints where you reset your bitmap and debug your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the code, I didn't see which line loads an image.

In your code, Bitmap is set for Canvas in method onSizeChanged, but the bitmap is an empty bitmap, you may try the code to load image

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.your_image) //-->here load your image
                                .copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true); 
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);//-->set bitmap
}
```

In addition, drawPath.reset() is called before invalidate(), do not reset path before onDraw(),

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();
        // respond to down, move and up events
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            drawPath = new Path();//--> use a new path after ACTION_UP
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }
        // redraw
        drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);//--> Draw on canvasBitmap
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, null);//--> draw canvasBitmap on canvas
        ...
    }
```

Comment: please check the new answer,  do not reset the drawPath before invalidate. In addtion, drawCanvas would not work on the view, you can just remove it.

Comment: its works but some other error is happen.. for example i draw J in black color then i change color green for draw A at taht time J also be as green color

Comment: updated. use drawCanvas to draw on canvasBitmap, and draw canvasBitmap in onDraw()